# How to iterate list of hashmaps and map hashmap to model

Tags: java

I have face with the problem of iterating list of hashmaps where I want to map a particular hashmap with model.

```
result = {ArrayList@10441}  size = 3
 0 = {HashMap@10443}  size = 3
  0 = {HashMap$Node@10453} "Id" -> "3"
  1 = {HashMap$Node@10454} "Name" -> "name3"
  2 = {HashMap$Node@10455} "TimeSpent" -> "6543"
 1 = {HashMap@10444}  size = 3
 2 = {HashMap@10445}  size = 3
```

I tried to iterate it such a way:

```
list.forEach(e -> SourceTargetMapper.MAPPER.toModel(new Source((Map<String, Object>) e)))
```

'toModel()' returns such a model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Foo {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long timeSpent;
}
```

But I cannot collect mapped models to list again. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

`foreach()` is not designed to map the stream elements : it is a terminal operation that "consumes" the stream with a `Consumer`.

Instead, use `map()` with `collect()` (supposing that `Model` is the returned type of `toModel()`:

```
List<Model> models = 
list.stream()
    .map(e -> SourceTargetMapper.MAPPER.toModel(new Source((Map<String, Object>) e)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I receive "Result of Stream.Collect()" is ignored in this case

Comment: It seems a IDe warning. Are you sure to assign the statement to a variable as in the answer  ?

Comment: 'SourceTargetMapper.MAPPER.toModel(new Source((Map<String, Object>) e)' should return Model object

Comment: What is the `toModel()` return ?

Comment: `List<Foo> models = ...` should be fine.